# Permission denied issue with fuse mount: "setting times of <FILE NAME>: Permission denied"

Tags: linux, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux, cloud

I have a Google cloud bucket being mounted on a RHEL8/FIPs GCP VM (gov't contract :().

It is a permanent mount point with this configuration in `/etc/fstab`:

```
<BUCKET_NAME> /usr/local/folder gcsfuse rw,allow_other,uid=1001,gid=1002,implicit_dirs
```

The 1001/1002 is a local admin account.

When this local admin tries to write to the /usr/local/folder, we get a the following error:

```
touch: setting times of 'test.txt': Permission denied
```

The local admin account has full ownership r/w (`chown -R admin:admin`) on the path that we are trying to write to.  I have never seen a "setting times of" error. Is this related to clock? Is it a time sync issue between the GCP bucket and the VM?  I have `user_allow_other` enabled in /etc/fuse.conf.  I have rebooted, remounted etc. Out of ideas.

Comment: Might be SELinux is enabled. Check the output of `sestatus` and see of `Current mode` and `Mode from config file` is set to `enforcing`. And also check the security context of the directory and its contents with `ls -lZ`. If it is SELinux, you can set it to permissive mode like this: `sudo setenforce permissive` and try setting times again. Doing that will allow actions to happen even if it goes against SELinx rules. If SELinux was the issue, you can set permissive permanently by editing the SELinux config file here with `sudo`: `sudo nano /etc/selinux/config`. Using nano in my example.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being IAM related and specifically related to gcsfuse. Using this guide: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/README.md,
I was able to deploy an API key for the service account associated with the VMs , re-mount the bucket, and the issue was resolved.